How do I set up pre-commit to use hooks from a private repository using a GIT_TOKEN?
I am trying to run pre-commit using hooks from a private repository using a GIT_TOKEN.
Before running pre-commit run --all-files, I insert my GIT_TOKEN (which has read access to the hooks repository) into the URL used for GitHub.
git config --global url."https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
git config --global url."https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

Nonetheless, I get the following error:
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/bin/git', 'fetch', 'origin', '--tags')
return code: 128
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
Check the log at /home/jdh/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log

I have the following simple .pre-commit-config.yaml:
- repo: https://github.com/JakobHavtorn/private-repository
  rev: v0.1.0
  hooks:
  - id: some-hook

I have looked through the documentation at https://pre-commit.com but was not able to find much detail on handling private hook repos.
I have verified that my token is correct and is set correctly in the URL (I can clone a different private repository).
I have tried running pre-commit run --all-files locally using try-repo, which works as expected.
I have also tried running the command with a SSH token defined for the github.com host via the /.ssh/config file (see below), which also works as expected.
host github.com
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
   User git

Thanks for your work on the tool and for taking the time with this question.
Edi: Solution (see comments)
It turned out that the git config commands were overwriting rather than appending. Hence, adding the --add flag to the git config calls allows both replacements to take effect:
git config --global --add url."https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
git config --global --add url."https://${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"


generally I recommend ssh urls for private repos -- but what you have should ~mostly work.  though I think the url format for github is https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/ so you're close but off by a bit

You're right, it was very close to working. It turns out our issue was specifying two global URL replacements (one for HTTPS and one for SSH). Somehow the SSH one was overwriting the HTTPS one. It is unclear to me exactly how, but removing the SSH URL replacement allowed pre-commit to successfully clone the repo.
The default when not specifiying x-access-token works in our case, though probably it's good to be explicit. Thanks!
